# Xamarin android GoogleAccountCredential

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-signin

I'm trying to use the Google Sign-In in Xamarin in order to create a YoutubeService instance. For now, i can get a GoogleSignInAccount with this function:

```
    public void Login()
    {
        if(account != null)
        {
            CreateYoutube();
            return;
        }

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
                .RequestServerAuthCode("112086459272-o965mju8hjqqr1fq333g3am9hqrm650e.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .RequestEmail()
                .RequestScopes(new Scope(YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube))
                .Build();

        googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .EnableAutoManage(this, this)
                .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .Build();

        OptionalPendingResult silentLog = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.SilentSignIn(googleClient);
        if (silentLog.IsDone)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("&Casting silentlog to google account");
            GoogleSignInResult result = (GoogleSignInResult)silentLog.Get();
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                account = result.SignInAccount;
                CreateYoutube();
            }
        }

        StartActivityForResult(Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(googleClient), 1598);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1598)
        {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                account = result.SignInAccount;
                CreateYoutube();
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working fine and i can get user's profile but the only way i've found to create a REST Api instance (like the youtube one) is by using the GoogleAccountCredential class (from the doc here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth). Here is the code i want to use:

```
    void CreateYoutube()
    {
        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.UsingOAuth2(
                                this /*Context*/,
                                YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube);
        credential.SelectedAccount = account;

        YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });
    }
```

but i can't find the api who contain GoogleAccountCredential in Xamarin. Is there another way to create a YoutubeService using oauth or an api who cover the GoogleAccountCredential class ?

Do not hesitate to ask me if you don't understand something in my question.
Thanks for reading, 
Tristan Roux

Answer (score 1):

> can't find the api who contain GoogleAccountCredential in Xamarin

You are looking the Nuget package: `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth`

#### Example Signin:

```
~~~    
// mGoogleApiClient is a fully configured GoogleApiClient with the scopes your app need
var signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1010);
~~~
```

Now in your OnActivityResult you can retrieve the `GoogleSignInAccount` from the received intent:

#### Example `OnActivityResult` and the `GoogleSignInAccount`:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1010)
    {
        var result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.SignInAccount;
        /// Do something with your "GoogleSignInAccount"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i'm already using this but i can't use the CreateYoutube method cause GoogleAccountCredential isn't part of the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth. Everything in my code work except this line: `GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.UsingOAuth2(
                                this /*Context*/,
                                YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube);
        credential.SelectedAccount = account;`